# Array to string conversion in... SQLquery and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having a problem with SQL query with an array in WHERE clause.
Example:
I have a few example array provide below

```
$a1[0] = "1"
$a1[1] = "2"
$a1[2] = "3"
```

PHP, SQL Statement. i using file_get_contents and json_decode to request array data.

```
$requestBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
$requestData = json_decode($requestBody,true);
    if($requestData){
         $invoice_no = $requestData["$a1[]"];
    }
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '" . $a1[]. "'";
```

if have hundred value of my array, how can I switch the array to string to able to perform my code?
i having ( Array to string conversion .. ) error in WHERE clause.

Comment: are you trying to convert array variable name like this $a1[] to string like this "$a1[]" or you want to convert the array values to string

Comment: This question is pretty confusing. Can you show us the exact content of `$requestBody` and `$requestData`?

Comment: Can you clear your example array conversion?

Comment: i have edited for clearly question and coversion

Comment: You have got to loop through your array in order to get the values out that you are looking for. You can't just make an array comparrison in a string value of your table.

Comment: if you want the query to have at least one of your array value you can use: WHERE name in " . implode(',',$a1) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Important! See bottom of answer for optimal solution!***

As I mentioned in my comment, you will have to loop through your array to retrieve the different indexes that you'd like to use for your search query. You can't simply chunk the array into a search string and hope to get results, which is why you're getting the errors that you're getting.

In order to loop through your array, we must first know the length of the array.
You can use the PHP function `count();` to achieve this.

Like so,

```
//$a being the name of your array
$length=count($a);
```

The way I'll go about doing this, is by constructing an SQL with a where clause. I will then create another SQL, which I will concatenate on the previous SQL, where I will then loop through the array to get each index with an `OR` statement to get every result where there is a match.

Full example:

```
<?php
$a[0] = 1;
$a[1] = 2;
$a[2] = 3;
$a[3] = 4;

$length=count($a);
$i=0;

$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ";

while($length > $i)
{    
    $sql .="name='$a[$i]' ";
    if($i+1 < $length)
    {
        $sql .= "OR ";
    }

    $i=$i+1;
}
echo $sql;   
?>
```

Outputs:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name='1' OR name='2' OR name='3' OR name='4'
```

Hope this was of any use.

There are also other ways of looping through an array, such as foreach where you also have the option to use keys.

---

### *Optimal answer:*

After having done some research, I've come to a conclusion, that the most optimal query you can do in the situation where you have hundreds of instances, is to use the `WHERE IN()` in SQL.

In order to achieve this, we'd need to perform an `implode();` which is a PHP function that will take your array, and transform it into a string. The way that works, is that you declare a separator in your `implode();` and that will become the joint connection of your array indexes in the string. As an example:

```
implode(', ', $a);
```

This will break up your array, and make the following string: "1, 2, 3, 4".

In other words, we transform your array into a string that matches the syntax of the `IN()` function in SQL.

Your query would then look like this:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN('" . implode( "', '", $a ) . "')";
```

The opposite of `implode();` would be `explode();` , where you take a string and turn it into an array, with the use of a separator. Same approach as with the `implode();` function.

Comment: you can just use `$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ('" . implode( "','", $a ) . "')";` but as this (and your solution) is prone to SQL injection I would not go that way.

Comment: I took the same approach as to his methods. ofc. he should use stored procedures, and/or sanitize his inputs. That's not what was the point of this though.

Comment: That the different in **implode** and **explode** how could i decide to choose to use ? Martin your approach method is not really suit my situation, cause i might have hundred case so that is not the best way for me. Thanks btw

Comment: `explode();` basically breaks a string into an array, breaking at the point of a separator that you define, and then target in your `explode();` . `implode();` is basically the opposite, where you take an array and make it into a string, where the separator is the joint connection of your new string. It's easier with examples, which you can look up rather easily. w3schools has some very simple examples that makes the use of the two functions easily understandable.